# InvalidOperationException when saving attribue value in Microsoft Metadirectory Services

Tags: c#

I'm writing a rule extension for Microsoft Identity Manager (FIM / MIM) and have a problem. What I want: I have value from `csentry["Manager"].Value` that I use to search Active directory. When I find the object I want, I get its DistinguishedName and try to save it to the metaverse attribute Manager. Like so: `mventry["Manager"].Value = MDN "Manager"` Unfortunately it fails with this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to access attribute manager. 
>   Reference values not accessible on MV objects.    at
>   Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.AttributeImpl.SetSingleValuedAttributeValue(Object
>   value)    at
>   Mms_ManagementAgent_HRMAExtension.MAExtensionObject.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMASynchronization.MapAttributesForImport(String
>   FlowRuleName, CSEntry csentry, MVEntry mventry) in
>   C:\Users\MIMS-Admin\Documents\HRMAExtension\HRMAExtension.cs:line 162

This is line 162:

`mventry["Manager"].Value = MDN;`

How do I set the reference value of the Manager attribute in the metaverse?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
case "LookUpDN":
    var MDN = string.Empty;
    if (mventry["Manager"].IsPresent)
    {
        // Do nothing ManagerDN distinguished name  is present
    }
    else
    {
        if (csentry["Manager"].Value !="0")
        {
            String[] DomainArray = new string[] { "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4" };
            foreach (string Domain in DomainArray)
            {                
                DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC="+Domain+",DC=COM");
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dir);
                search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(EmployeeID=" + csentry["Manager"] + "))";
                SearchResult searchresult = search.FindOne();
                if (searchresult !=null)
                {
                    MDN = searchresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString(); 
                }
            }
        }
        mventry["Manager"].Value = MDN;
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the DN (DistinguisedName) is used as a reference and cannot be changed. Think of it as primary/foreign keys in a database. `Manager` field in Metaverse is designated to be one of those "Reference" fields and you cannot modify it like this.

A somewhat of a solution is presented here: https://identityunderground.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/ilm-quick-solution-getting-attribute-data-from-a-referenced-object/